# Calculating a circle's velocity

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, physics

I've been working on this problem for a bit, and it doesn't seem too hard, but I'm getting tired and it seems more and more complicated the more I try (but it's probably really easy).

My goal is to have a ball bounce off another ball. Seems easy enough.

Ball 2 is controlled by the user's mouse (so far it's sort of like single player pong, but it's a circle instead of a rectangle) so its velocity doesn't matter.

Ball 1 has a few attributes, including dx (the x distance it moves every frame) and dy (dx, but for the y coordinate)

The problem with what I have so far is that you don't know what values will be positive and what will be negative (so the speed can severely increase or decrease instantly), you might be able to fix this using many else if's, but I'm too confused to think right now.

Here is the important part of this function. Also, I've tried to set it up so that dx + dy is always the same, even when the numbers change, so that it looks more natural.

```
if (collision(ball, paddle)) {
    diffX = paddle.x-ball.x;
    diffY = paddle.y-ball.y;
    totalVel = ball.dx+ball.dy;
    dir = {
      x : diffX/(diffX+diffY)*-totalVel,
      y : diffY/(diffX+diffY)*-totalVel
    };
    ball.dx = dir.x;
    ball.dy = dir.y;
  }
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the full code
https://jsfiddle.net/a2prr0uw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly let's start by defining what a "bounce" is - the *speed* is the same, but the *direction* (on both axis) will be inverted. If we treat dx and dy like a vector, then we can first get the incoming speed of the ball like this:

```
var ballSpeed = Math.sqrt((ball.dx * ball.dx) + (ball.dy * ball.dy));
```

The above value will always be positive, regardless of what dx and dy are doing.

Next, we'll need the incoming direction of the ball - that bit is the same as what you've currently got:

```
diffX = paddle.x-ball.x;
diffY = paddle.y-ball.y;
```

However if we treat this as a vector too, it essentially has a totally unknown length. So, let's normalise it so it's a direction vector with a length of 1:

```
var distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));
diffX /= distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall;
diffY /= distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall;
```

diffX and diffY is now a normalised direction vector - the direction the ball is currently going in - and ballSpeed is the speed we'd like it to go.

So now we'll apply our bounce - flip the direction and retain the speed. That becomes this:

```
dir = {
  x : -diffX * ballSpeed,
  y : -diffY * ballSpeed
};
```

Put it all together and we end up with this:

```
if (collision(ball, paddle)) {
    diffX = paddle.x-ball.x;
    diffY = paddle.y-ball.y;
    // How fast is the ball coming in?
    var ballSpeed = Math.sqrt((ball.dx * ball.dx) + (ball.dy * ball.dy));
    // How far is the ball from the paddle?
    var distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

    // Normalise diffX and diffY so we have a direction vector:
    diffX /= distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall;
    diffY /= distanceBetweenPaddleAndBall;

    // Apply the bounce and the original ball speed:
    dir = {
      x : -diffX * ballSpeed,
      y : -diffY * ballSpeed
    };
    ball.dx = dir.x;
    ball.dy = dir.y;
  }
```

And [here it is as a fork of your fiddle too](https://jsfiddle.net/xbnfc3g1/).

Comment: No problem! And don't forget to sleep :)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm in America so it's 6:30pm right now

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but some considerations on your bouncing logic:

- you have to calculate the balls direction (dy/dx)
- the collision has also a direction (angle beween both centers = b.x-p.x / b.y-p.y)
- the angle after bouncing has to be calculated based on these two angles: using ther 2nd for mirroring
- to calculate the new dx & dy after collision you will need the original velocity Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx)+Math.pow(dy))) of the ball
- based on this velocity and the new direction you can calc the new dx & dy